# Untyped dataset param not accepting typed dataset in c#

Tags: c#

We are having a dataaccess layer and it is having one interface with a function with untyped dataset. when we are passing typed dataset from entity layer to dataaccess layer we are getting an error. please help to resolve the error.

CODE:

```
public interface diNonTransactional
{
    int ExecuteDataAdapterDataTableWithParams(IDbCommand podbCommand, ref DataTable pdtDataTable);
}
```

Below function is solving my issue but i don't know how to implement the function in dataaccess layer.please help me how to implement.

New code

```
int ExecuteDataAdapterDataTableWithParams<T>(IDbCommand podbCommand, ref T pdtDataTable) where T :` DataTable;
```

My Old Implemenation:

```
public int ExecuteDataAdapterDataTableWithParams(IDbCommand podbCommand, ref DataTable pdtDT)
{
IDataAdapter ldaDataAdapter = default(IDataAdapter);
IDbTransaction lodbTrans = default(IDbTransaction);
int liFetchedRows = 0;
lodbTrans = EstablishConnection();
try
{
podbCommand.Connection = coConnection;
podbCommand.Transaction = lodbTrans;
ldaDataAdapter = GetDataAdapter(ref podbCommand);
ldaDataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table",  pdtDT.TableName);
liFetchedRows = ldaDataAdapter.Fill(pdtDT.DataSet);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
throw (ex);
}
finally
{
CloseConnection(ref lodbTrans);
}
return liFetchedRows;
}
```

Comment: What is the error? What type are you trying to pass?

Comment: Why do you need to pass `DataTable` as `ref`. `ref` is almost not needed

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the fact that the parameter is declared 'ref'.  When a parameter is declared 'ref' it means that a new object may be passed back out of the method and assigned to the original variable.  If you're trying to pass in a typed DataTable then the original variable is that type.  Because the parameter is declared simply as type DataTable, that means that you could pass out an untyped DataTable and that could not be assigned to the typed DataTable variable, hence the compilation error.  If the parameter must be declared 'ref' because you want to pass an object out of the method then you can't pass in a typed DataTable as it stands.  You would have to make the method generic and place a constraint on that generic type parameter like so:

```
public interface diNonTransactional
{
    int ExecuteDataAdapterDataTableWithParams<TDataTable>(IDbCommand podbCommand, ref TDataTable pdtDataTable)
        where TDataTable : DataTable;
}
```

Of course, you then need to be able to provide an implementation that can handle that.  Possibly a better option would be to make the interface generic and then you can fix the type of TDataTable when you declare a class that implements it.

Comment: plase tell me how can i implement this function

Comment: int ExecuteDataAdapterDataTableWithParams<T>(IDbCommand podbCommand, ref T pdtDataTable) where T :` DataTable;